# PHP and my current HTML w/ CSS files

Tags: php, html, css

This question will more than likely result in an easy answer, however I am at a roadblock until hopefully someone can  help, as I am new to PHP.

So I had a basic registration page in HTML and styled in CSS for my website, however it obviously did nothing. So I acquired the necessary PHP files to make it all work, and tested the PHP on a localserver and it was excellent as anticipated.

However my question is, how can I bring the functionality of the PHP into my already created SignUp.html page?

Or do I need to somehow style the PHP and scrap my current html and css files?

I'll attach my current basic html code in the event that helps.

```
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>

    <div id="form-data">
        <fieldset>

            <div class="fieldgroup">
                <label for="name"> Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="name">
            </div>
            <div class="fieldgroup">
                <label for="name">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name">
            </div>

            <div class="fieldgroup">
                <label for="name">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name">
            </div>

            <div class="fieldgroup">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email">
            </div>

            <div class="fieldgroup">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password">
            </div>

            <div class="fieldgroup">
                <p class="right">By clicking register you agree to our <a target="_blank" href="#">policy</a>.</p>
                <input type="submit" value="Sign up" class="submit">
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Comment: *"how can I bring the functionality of the PHP into my already created SignUp.html page?"* - You can instruct Apache to treat `.html` as PHP. That, or rename the extension to `.php`

Comment: Wrap it in a `form` tag and direct it to the PHP file

Comment: plug it into a database

Answer (score 1):

Rename the .html file to the .php extension and then put the PHP code into it.
Probably something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['sent'])) 
{
   // PROCESS FORM IN PHP HERE
}
```

will help you when modifying the submit button to:

```
<input type="submit" name="sent" value="Sign up" class="submit">
```

Comment: If i rename my SignUp.html to SignUp.php I lose the CSS when loading the SignUp.php in a LocalServer?

Comment: The page fetches the css, not the other way around, so this should not be a problem

Answer (score 0):

You can change the extension of the `.html` files to `.php` to bring the functionality of PHP to your files. The HTML will still be treated as HTML, so there is no need to change the HTML markup if you change the extension.

You can also "*instruct Apache to treat `.html` as PHP.*" as @Fred-ii- said.

For running the form through PHP, you can either direct the form to a .PHP file like so:

```
<form action="phpfile.php" method="*post OR get*">
```

or you can run it on the page the form is on like so:

```
<form action="" method="*post OR get*">
<!-- Form Contents Here -->
</form>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// PHP code here
}

?>
```

Comment: "instruct Apache to treat .html as PHP." thats not a line of code

Comment: It's also just a bad way to approach the "problem".

Comment: Oops, I meant to quote him. Fixed.

Comment: @Locke Hey man I appreciate your comment, but when I do what you say, and run SignUp.php in my localserver it doesn't display the css?

Comment: Is your CSS in an external file?

Comment: @Locke Yes. It is linked with an <link href="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/WebSite/LocalTest.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> in the beginning of the SignUp.php file

Comment: Edit your post to contain the full SignUp.php code.